# How do I reference a class object in a different function?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c#, I am creating a quiz program (I am at the very beginning) and I have generated a class with a question, 4 answers and a correct answer. I have created one question in Public form1, How do I make the correct answer show up in a messagebox when button1 is clicked?

```
namespace Prog02
{

    public class Question
    {
        public string Que { get; }
        public string Ans1 { get; }
        public string Ans2 { get; }
        public string Ans3 { get; }
        public string Ans4 { get; }
        public string CorrectAns { get; set; }

        public Question(string que, String ans1, String ans2, String ans3, String ans4, String correctans)
        {
            Que = que;
            Ans1 = ans1;
            Ans2 = ans2;
            Ans3 = ans3;
            Ans4 = ans4;
            CorrectAns = correctans;
        }


    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //define question1
            Question Question1 = new Question("What number is lowest", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Question1.CorrectAns);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Question1` would need to be a class member in `Form1`. Then you'll be able to use it in `button1_Click`

Comment: How Would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have created an instance of the `Question` class directly in the constructor of the form (within `Form1`, below the method call `InitializeComponent`). The specified variable `Question1` is only valid in this local scope of this specific function. So if you want to access it from outside of this function, you have to make it available in the class. This can be achieved by declaring a field within the class like `private Question question;` directly before the constructor call and changing your assignment to `question = new Question(...);`

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Question question;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.question = new Question("What number is lowest", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1");
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.question.CorrectAns);
    }
}
```

Comment: What does adding ```this.question``` do? surely the "this" isn't necessary?

Comment: @UnderQualified The [`this`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) keyword just ensures, that you are accessing something that is within the instance. In your specific case this would not be necessary but if you hald a method with a parameter called `x` and you would like to access a field with the name `x`, just writing `x` would refer to the "most local thing" which would be the parameter. If you were to write `this.x` instead, it would refer to the field within your instance.

Answer (score 1):

You should move out the `question` instance and make it a field.
Also there were some other wrong parts with the code. 
Here is the full code with the fixes.
Added comments for describing the changes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Prog02
{

    public class Question
    {
        // Added "private set" to the properties below 
        public string Que { get; private set;}
        public string Ans1 { get; private set;}
        public string Ans2 { get; private set;}
        public string Ans3 { get; private set;}
        public string Ans4 { get; private set;}
        public string CorrectAns { get; private set; }

        public Question(string que, String ans1, String ans2, String ans3, String ans4, String correctans)
        {
            Que = que;
            Ans1 = ans1;
            Ans2 = ans2;
            Ans3 = ans3;
            Ans4 = ans4;
            CorrectAns = correctans;
        }


    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Created a private field for holding the question instance.
        private Question question1;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //define question1
            question1 = new Question("What number is lowest", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1");

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Use the instance here ("question1" instead of "Question1")
            MessageBox.Show(question1.CorrectAns);
        }
    }
}
```